# Is there any way to create a infinity loop in socket server

Tags: node.js

I'm creating a game like [this](https://trustdice.win/crash)

and I want to my server create a random number and start counting from one and when it reaches that random number I want to send to all of the players that the game is over and start the new match again.

I think the best way to do it is when a new round starts an infinity loop start and it checks timer with that random number and if the timer reaches that random number break loop and call function to broadcast data.

I've searched for a solution to create this about two days and I found nothing in node js.

so please share any idea

this is my base server code:

```
    var net = require('net');
    var clients = [];
    var random = CreateRandom();//this function create a random number
    var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    // Put this new client in the list
    clients.push(socket);
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        //do something with this data
    });



})
function Brodcast(random){ // i have no idea to where should use this function
    for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
        clients[i].write(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use the [setIntervall](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) function to call a function that counts up every second or use the [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) function to broadcast a message after your random time span has elapsed.